# Raspberry Pi Google assistant

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I need help on where I have gone wrong. I followed https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-google-assistant/. The program asks me to input a request but it doesn't output the answer through the speakers. I have attached when happens when I talk to the microphone (send a request).

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id raspberry-pi--home1 --device-model-id raspberry-pi--home1-google-assistant-fr9vci
INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
INFO:root:Using device model raspberry-pi--home1-google-assistant-fr9vci and device id 2c9c8f3a-6286-11ec-b862-b827ebae3b0b
Press Enter to send a new request...
INFO:root:Recording audio request.
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "what".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "what time".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "what time is".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "what time is it".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "what  time is it".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "what time  is it".
INFO:root:End of audio request detected.
INFO:root:Stopping recording.
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "what time is it".
INFO:root:Playing assistant response.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 458, in main
    continue_conversation = assistant.assist()
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 241, in wrapped_f
    return self.call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 329, in call
    do = self.iter(result=result, exc_info=exc_info,
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 279, in iter
    return fut.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 433, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 333, in call
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 154, in assist
    self.conversation_stream.write(resp.audio_out.audio_data)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/audio_helpers.py", line 326, in write
    buf = normalize_audio_buffer(buf, self.volume_percentage)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/audio_helpers.py", line 57, in normalize_audio_buffer
    buf = arr.tostring()
AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'tostring'
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't qualify this as an answer. Just been going through the same issue when installing Assistant SDK on a raspberry. Unfortunately haven't done much with Python, but I think the key is

```
File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-backages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/audio_helpers.py", line 57, in normalize_audio_buffer
buf = arr.tostring()
AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'tostring'
```

Possibly some type casting issue? or a deprecated function. Tomorrow I'll roll back to an older Python and try again.

Diego.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue. By editing file `/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-backages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/audio_helpers.py` in line 57 and change `tostring` to `tobytes` it should work.